# How to determine the proper dimension of a TensorFlow embedding_column

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to `tensorflow` and trying to understand `embedding_column`. It takes a parameter `dimension` that isn't totally making sense to me.

In this example (from a Google tutorial), `dimension` = 8

```
thal = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'thal', ['fixed', 'normal', 'reversible'])
thal_embedding = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(thal, dimension=8)
```

Which I had assumed was 2^3, since there are 3 possibilities and each can be "on" or "off".

However in the documentation example:

```
video_id = categorical_column_with_identity(
    key='video_id', num_buckets=1000000, default_value=0)
columns = [embedding_column(video_id, 9),...]
```

I'm not tracking why `dimension` is 9 here. Can anyone explain what the rule should be?

Answer (score 1):

The three on-off possibilities you mentioned are One-Hot Encodings where a value can be 0 or 1. Embeddings are similar but with one key
difference that they can have any value. These are useful in places where number of categories are large and one-hot encoding is not feasible.
So we can use a lower dimension than what we get by one-hot encoding. So basically embedding dimension is an extra parameter to be tuned.

Ex: For 3 categories

```
    One-Hot:

    [ [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]

    Same with Embeddings and dimension 2

    [ [-0.426, 0.987], [0.657, 0.222], [0.398, -0.725] ]
```